# Number of $n-1$-dimensional subspaces of $n$-dimensional space over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I got a question with two parts.

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ - finite field with $p$  elements.

a) How many $1$-dimensional subspaces $V$ has.

b) How many $n-1$-dimensional subspaces $V$ has.

I solved (a) with action of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ on $V$, but I didn't succeed to solve (b) with similar idea..

I still prefer an idea with action of groups.. thanks !

Comment: What's the dimension of the perpendicular subspace $S^{\perp}$ to an $n-1$-dimensional subspace $S$?

Comment: With standard euclidian inner-product ?

Comment: Sure, I should have stated, with inner product $\langle u,v\rangle=\sum u_iv_i$.

Comment: And is it a bijection ? That is, the answers of two parts are the same ?

Comment: You tell me, the hint was to try and see if you could find the answer yourself with a little nudging. Feel free to write up an answer if you're confident in your answer.

Comment: I think it is, cuz the direct sum of subspace and the orthogonal complement is the whole space, unless i'm missing something

Comment: You're right (for an inner product on a finite dimensional vector space that is true anyway). So now you just need to show that the map which sends a $1$-dimensional subspace to its orthogonal complement is a bijection.

Comment: Warning: Because there is no (useful) concept of positive element in $\Bbb{F}_p$ it may easily happen that the entire space is not the sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement. For example with $p=2$, $n=2$, the subspace generated by the vector $(1,1)$ is its own orthogonal complement. But you still get a bijection between the 1D and the $(n-1)$D subspaces from that!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

There is a bijection between subspaces of dimension $k$ and $k\times n$ matrices of rank $k$ in reduced row-echelon form.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will only be helpful if you have some background in (projective) geometry.

The number of $1$-dimensional subspaces in a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $\mathbb F_q$ corresponds to the number of points in a projective space of (geometric) dimension $n-1$ over the same field, denoted by $|\mathbb P^{n-1}(\mathbb F_q)|$. Since a projective space can be thought of as the disjoint union of an affine space of the same dimension and a hyperplane at infinity, i.e. a projective space of a dimension one smaller, we have that

$$ |\mathbb P^{n-1}(\mathbb F_q)| = |\mathbb A^{n-1}(\mathbb F_q)| + |\mathbb P^{n-2}(\mathbb F_q)| = q^{n-1} + |\mathbb P^{n-2}(\mathbb F_q)| . $$

Therefore, inductively, the answer is given by:

$$ |\mathbb P^{n-1}(\mathbb F_q)| = q^{n-1} + q^{n-2} + \dots + p + 1 = \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}. $$

Because of projective duality, a projective space has the same number of points and hyperplanes so this is actually the answer to the other question as well.